# Android compatibility package Fragment as inner static class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been using the Android compatibility Package but i encountered the following issue, it seems that whenever i create a Fragment as an inner static class on my application and try to start that activity the it display the following error

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment org.wr.CreditCardHolderActivity.CreditCardHolderFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

And when i separate the fragment and the activity everything work smoothly, anyone know why? and how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: how is the fragment being loaded into the container? Via layout XML or in code? I've not tried the former but have had no problems with static inner fragment classes with the latter. BTW I'm using v1 of the compat lib.

Comment: i have a layout with the fragment with contains obviously the <fragment> tag along with the name of the inner class.

Comment: have you looked at the FragmentLayoutSupport example in API demos? It refernces a static inner fragment class via: **<fragment class="com.example.android.apis.support.app.FragmentLayoutSupport$TitlesFragment"...** . with the fragment defined in **FragmentLayoutSupport.java**

Comment: Well excellent that might work i'll try it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an inner class Fragment like:

```
public class SomethingFragment extends Fragment {    
  public static final class TypeFragment extends BaseFragment
  {

    public static Fragment newInstance()
    {
        return new TypeFragment();
    }

    private View mRootView;
    private ListView mListView;

    /**
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
     *      android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_list, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_listview);
        return mRootView;
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure your qualifier is **public** when the FragmentActivity tries to reinitiate the fragment it doesn't call it from the concrete class it will handle it from the abstract FragmentActivity, and if your inner class Fragment is private the Activity has no reference to onSaveState, onRestoreState, initialise etc..

`private` to `public` fixed it for me!

**Update:**

Have a look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java

The `instantiate` method calls `newInstance()` when trying to restore the `Fragment` from a saved state (where the fragment was completely destroyed).

The `newInstance` method requires the class to be publicly accessible, so when defined as an inner class this means it has to be `public` and `static` where appropriate.

Hope this clears up some future questions.

Comment: Is never late to accept the answer thank you I forgot it to do it.…

Comment: I don't understand: why is it important for fragments to be public? will it cause any exceptions? if so, in which cases? if the only class that uses the fragment is the activity, why not set it as private static class ? if i use the fragment only for viewPager, is it ok to set it as private?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Well its actually the `FragmentManager` that maintains the lifecycle of the `Fragment` not the activity. 
I would need to check source code, but all fragments are checked for public empty constructors, as that is what the fragment manager will instantiate when it needs to create the fragment, So if your fragments are in a different scope to the `FragmentManager` this of course is not possible. (At an guess I think it would call https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())

Comment: i don't think the viewpager needs the fragmentManager, no? if it's the only reason, i think that if my activity has only a viewpager with fragments inside it, it should be fine.

Comment: The `FragmentPagerAdapter` does need the FragmentManager which is what handles instantiating the correct fragment. `ViewPager` is just a view. After searching the code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java `instantiate` calls `newInstance` which requires a public (static) constructor otherwise the class loader can not access it.